# Why is uglify-js-plugin producing such a large cache in node_modules/.cache?

Tags: node.js, webpack

There's a `node_modules/.cache/uglify-js-plugin` folder in my project which is taking up a **huge** amount of space:

[image: scr]

I don't have it as a direct dependency but it must be one of webpack's.

It seems I can delete it with no visible effects but running `npm i` again it comes back with a smaller size at first but slowly grows again.

Why is it creating all these folders and is there anything I can do to prevent it?

- Windows 10
- Node v10
- npm v6
- Webpack v4.12

Comment: Have you found any information about this behavior ? I have exactly the same problem...